# Dropdown Menu is always active and show

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue with Bootstrap (Bootswatch) Dropdown menu, I have been using it before, but not sure where and what I am missing the drop-down stays open and active. here is my code I am helping a friend to build an MVC basic CRUD Operation. 
I appreciate your help very much, please let me know if you need any other details or code to help me.

Home

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

        <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">لیستی خوێندکاران</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu show" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(0px, 40px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">خوێندکاری نوێ</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">لیستی خوێندکاران</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            </div>
            </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">لیستی  مامۆستایان</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu show" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(0px, 40px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">مامۆستای نوێ</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">لیستی مامۆستایان</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">لیستی  بەشەکان</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu show" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(0px, 40px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">بەشی  نوێ</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">لیستی بەشەکان</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            </div>

    </ul>
</div>
<div>


    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        @Html.Partial("/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml")


        @*<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="گەڕان" type="text">*@
        @*<button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>*@
    </form>
</div>
```

here is what is looks like. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check the console log in the chrome developer window, see whether it showing help full error information.

Answer (score 0):

just remove `show` class from all divs with `dropdown-menu` class. i.e, `<div class="dropdown-menu show"...` to `<div class="dropdown-menu"...`

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

        <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">لیستی خوێندکاران</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(0px, 40px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">خوێندکاری نوێ</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">لیستی خوێندکاران</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">لیستی  مامۆستایان</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(0px, 40px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">مامۆستای نوێ</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">لیستی مامۆستایان</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">لیستی  بەشەکان</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(0px, 40px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">بەشی  نوێ</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">لیستی بەشەکان</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            </div>

        </ul>
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: When I do delete the show from the div it doesn't work, but I have not checked it with Chrome. Let me remove the show and try with Chrome.

Comment: I have just checked with chrome, ff, opera, edge. Its working in these four browsers. I didn't check the older browsers though. And I have removed your c# code in my example to reproduce it in my env. Just informing.

Answer (score 0):

I had package version incompatiblly problem by running update-package I was able to get it working. Thank you for your help and your time investigating the issue with me.